# Slow SOAP request after certain time - .net WCF

Tags: performance, wcf, soap, .net-4.8

When we send a SOAP request to our customer's SOAP server, we get very different response times on the first call and if exactly 1 minute elapses between 2 calls. It all depends on which machine the client is running on:

Scenario1: Fast - From Developer PC (Windows 10)
1st request: 1.2 seconds
2nd request: 0.4 seconds
Further request within 1 minute: 0.4 seconds
Further requests, if last request is more than 1 minute ago: 0.4 seconds

Scenario 2: Slow - From customer server (Windows Server 2013)
1st request: 15 seconds
2nd request: 0.4 seconds
Further request within 1 minute: 0.4 seconds
Further requests, if last request is more than 1 minute ago: 15 seconds

Scenario 3: Fast - From customer server (Windows Server 2022)
Fast. Same values as in Scenario 1.

The time period when it gets slow is exactly 1 minute.
We are using WCF with .net 4.8.

We made tests from several diffent client PCs with Windows 10 - All of them are fast.
We made tests with SOAP UI from the "slow" customer server. The result was also fast.

Comment: You've determined in some diagnostic way that only when the SOAP protocol is used, Scenario 2 is the outcome? Is it slow with normal HTTP(S) get? Network performance is fast but just when SOAP protocol is slow? Many windows services in play here, Network, IIS, Caching, HTTP(or HTTPS), connection break down/build back up, HTTP ver 1, ... . Not to mentioned outdated OS.

Comment: So your question is do you want to compare the speed of response of each program in these configurations. If this is the case, use the control variable method to better rule out surprises.

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem was caused by the use of a certificate on the server that was not based on a valid root certificate.

In this case, the windows of the client machine is trying to update it's CTL (certificate trust list) on each call. This caused the performance problem.

The problem could be solved, by creating and using a new valid certificate on server and client.

The measured times are now:
1st call: 1,2 sec
Further calls: 0,3 sec